# jdbctemplate.query doesn't work with any null value in select sql

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, web, jdbc

When i use `jdbcTemplate.query` which just give me all books I'm getting an exception but i wanna to get list of books with all null values

```
public List<Book> index() {
return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM Book", new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Book.class));
}
```

I get that its not `BeanPropertyRowMapper` cuz i debuged and its work well and the whole problem may be in query

> Error: [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver
>
> - Resolved [org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'null' to required type 'int' for
>   property 'person_id'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [null] to type [int] for value 'null'; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null value cannot
>   be assigned to a primitive type]

Comment: Without seeing the error it is impossible to answer?

Comment: That still is not the exception and stacktrace, that doesn't add anything byt only that you are issueing a wrong request.

Comment: But there are no exceptions or stacktrace in output

Comment: check your logs. Error 400 is client error if there was an error in the query or maping it would give a 500 error.